# Using for loop within an if-statement in R

Tags: r, loops, categorical-data

I have a problem, where I need to multiply estimated growth rates on base-numbers. The growth rates are stored in a matrix (see data example below) and so are the base-numbers. This itself is easy - the problem is that I have several growth rates for several types of entities behind the base-numbers.

```
set.seed(1223)
Typ1.rates <- c(1.1,1.2,0.9,1.4)
Typ2.rates <- c(1.4,5.2,1.9,0.4)
g.rates <- t(cbind(Typ1.rates, Typ2.rates))


x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(16, rate=.2), ncol=4)*100)
x$Type <- c(1,1,1,2)
```

So if the type == 1 for a given row, I want to multiply the first observation with the first observation in Typ1.rates (that is [1,1]) and so on.

This is obvisously easy if I have two types of rates, but if I have 25 types, and large matrices/data frames, this becomes tough to do manually.

Anyone with a good way of doing this?

If any more explanation or data/code is needed, please let me know

EDIT:

Using the seed set above I hope to get the following matrix

```
                       V1           V2           V3            V4
1: 141.8580480 1149.9857213  303.4234747 1014.77951629
2: 770.1481988  407.0247813 1219.3383377  156.62140585
3: 554.1117304  983.2339648  239.1584652   50.52442765
4: 584.8300270 1207.7605414 2252.7680594   43.13052390
```

Comment: did you check if your example is error free?

Comment: Perhaps change the 16 to 40 in the dataframe you assign ?
Like so, in order to have 10 rows and manage to attach the `type` column.
`x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(40, rate=.2), ncol=4)*100)`

Comment: It will preferred if you'd first add a `set.seed` (so we could reproduce your data) and then show the exact desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that is now done above. Result and seed.

Comment: `700.1347*1.1 = 770.1482` how come its `840.1616`? i guess I have got the question wqrong it seems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either using a simple multiplication

```
set.seed(1223)
g.rates[x[, 5], ] * x[, -5]  # Note in your question you missed to include Typ2.rates
```

Or using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .SD*g.rates[x$Type,] , .SDcols = paste0("V", 1:4)]
#        V1        V2        V3         V4
#1 141.8580 1149.9857  303.4235 1014.77952
#2 770.1482  407.0248 1219.3383  156.62141
#3 554.1117  983.2340  239.1585   50.52443
#4 584.8300 1207.7605 2252.7681   43.13052
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg yeah !! Why did i complicate?! please write it as an answer

Comment: i have mentioned it as a comment @DavidArenburg thanks

Comment: I tried the line your wrote, but gives the following error: `Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , g.rates[Type, ] * .SD, by = "Type") : 
  unused argument (by = "Type")`

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa its a data.table..sorry i forgot to add `setDT()`

Comment: Perfect @joel.wilson : I should probably have spotted that. However, when I run the, though it does something right obiously, I don't get the correct rates. See:


`pred <- setDT(x)[, g.rates[Type,]*.SD,by = .(Type)]
pred[1,2:5]/x[1,1:4]
    V1  V2  V3  V4
1: 1.1 1.4 0.9 1.2`

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa didn't get your query

Comment: Understand it is confusing :) I have added a seed and a desired outcome. 

When I stored the matrix generated by your command and divided the first row by the first row in x, I should've gotten the vector Typ1.rates, however what I got was `vec <- c(1.1 1.4 0.9 1.2)`

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa i am unable to get .. did you try the first solution? is it giving the expected output?

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa i have updated my answer with the seed - 1223, both my solutions give the same output but thats not matching with yours. Could you recheck your numbers again?

Comment: The latest change does it correctly. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

You can make conditions directly in the dataframe to assign new values like so:

```
x[x$Type == 1, ]
```

This will display all the `x` values that match `==1`

What you need next is to use the rates you have added, so for example :

```
x[x$Type == 1, ] * Typ1.rates
```

**Final code**

Let's say you want to loop through all the types you have and use conditions,  like so:

```
Typ1.rates <- c(1.1,1.2,0.9,1.4)
Typ2.rates <- c(1.4,5.2,1.9,0.4)
g.rates <- t(cbind(Typ1.rates, Typ1.rates))


x <- as.data.frame(matrix(rexp(16, rate=.2), ncol=4)*100)
x$Type <- c(1,1,1,2)

for(i in 1:nrow(g.rates)) {
    # We apply the change to the n-1 columns in order to prevent any change to the type column
    x[x$Type == i, 1:(ncol(x)-1) ] <- x[x$Type == i, 1:(ncol(x) -1) ] * as.list(g.rates[i,])
}
```

This should be pretty fast to be executed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. However, do I need the "eval(parse(" part. Couldn't I just call the i'th row in the g.rates data.frame/matrix, as long as the rates are row-sorted by type?

Comment: I edited the answer in order to work with that solution, the dataframe also needs to be converted to a list for a multiplication by row, I have got consistent results with that method.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R`

```
 do.call(rbind, Map(`*`, split(x[-5], x$Type), 
                 split(g.rates, row(g.rates))))
 #        V1       V2        V3        V4
 #1.1 141.8580 1341.650  303.4235 869.81101
 #1.2 840.1617  373.106 1896.7485 100.68519
 #1.3 453.3641  983.234  292.3048  50.52443
 #2   584.8300 1207.761 2252.7681  43.13052
```